# MQTT Packet Loss Simulator in terminal

Tags: macos, networking, mqtt, iot

How can I simulate packet loss in mac os? 
I want test the different scenarios for MQTT QoS Levels. 
Are there any frameworks for this approaches or simple terminal
programs?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for OSX, but there are a couple of ways to do it on Linux, so may be you could try them in the VM.

1. You can use iptables to drop a given % of packets using the ipt_statistic module which is part of the [iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) package
2. Use something like the [CORE](http://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/core) Network emulator. This lets you create whole networks and set bandwidth and packet drop rates. They provide VMWare [image](http://downloads.pf.itd.nrl.navy.mil/core/vmware-image/) pre-installed

Answer (score 0):

Because MQTT uses TCP, it is not typically affected by IP/Ethernet packet loss, until it gets serious enough that timeouts occur and the whole TCP connection is dropped. MQTT message re-transmission only occurs when a connection drops and then is re-established.

As such, you may be better off using something like a proxy or TCP port-forwarder between your client and server, so that you can simulate the connection dropping.

socat is an example of a simple TCP port forwarder:
http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

The following command listens on port 2883 and forwards connections to 1883 on the same machines:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2883,reuseaddr,fork TCP:localhost:1883
```

Typing Ctrl-C will cause it to drop the TCP connection.
socat is available from homebrew on Mac OS X.

Comment: Packet loss in the MQTT protocol is usually due to flow control in the MQTT broker, ie. it will become so bogged down that it is forced to drop messages for QOS 0. QOS 1 and 2 just means they are priority over QOS 0. For the brokers that we test that happens after a lot of connections, like 30000 or 40000.